# How to tell if a Random variable $Y_N$ is a discrete-time martingale?

Tags: conditional-expectation, martingales, filtrations

I understand that the definition of a discrete-time martingale in a filtered probability space $(\Omega, F, \mathbb{P}, (F_n)_{n\geq 0} ) $ is $M = (M_n)_{n\geq 0}$ such that:

1. $M$ is adapted with respect to $(F_n)_{n\geq 0}$,
2. $M_n$ is intergrable for all $n \geq0$,
3. $M_N = E[M_{n+1}|F_n]$.

But how do you tell if a sequence of random variables $Y_N$ say, is adapted to $F_N$? I will provide a example to help understand my question.

Let $(\Omega, F, \mathbb{P}, ) $ be a probability space, where $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is a sequence of independent random variables such that $X_N \sim LN(\mu, \sigma ^2).$ Let $F_0 := {(\emptyset, \Omega)}$ and let $F_N$ be the $\sigma$ - field generated by $X_1, ..., X_n$. $S_0 := 0$ and $S_n := \sum_{k = 1}^{n}{X_k}- an $.

Find $b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $(Y_n)_{n\geq 0}$ defined as:

$Y_N := S_{n}^{2} - bn$.

Is a martingale with respect to the filtration $(F_n)_{n\geq 0}$.

How can I prove that $(Y_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is adapted to the filtration? I understand how to prove the other two conditions, if it has finite expectation it is integrable and then I can find out $b$ by using property (3).

Comment: Since $Y_n$ is a measurable function of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$, it is neasurable with respect to the $\sigma$-field generated by them. But don't forget you'll have to find both $a$ and $b$ to make it a martingale (the results won't surprise you too much, I guess).

Comment: Thank you, I think my main issue is how can you tell that $Y_N$ is a measurable function? I understand the definition of a measurable function but I find applying it in situations like these quite confusing.

Comment: $Y_n$ is $\mathcal F_n$-measurable iff for each $t\in\mathbb R$, $$ \{\omega: Y_n(\omega) \leqslant t\} \in\mathcal F_n.$$